# Need a palette with 64 colours: simple heatmap question

Tags: r, colors, heatmap

I have a several thousand matrices which look something like the following:

```
         [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]     [,6]
 [1,] 560.5681 526.3265 501.4808 447.4124 475.3496 487.1298
 [2,] 556.7537 525.3711 460.2989 412.7424 478.1070 506.8339
 [3,] 570.1362 534.5701 461.2309 476.0936 509.1480 491.3332
 [4,] 564.1036 538.4911 593.1357 573.0606 532.7869 496.5737
 [5,] 606.3170 583.7723 536.8325 614.4326 514.1198 427.6375
 [6,] 555.8331 576.4716 642.0229 617.1337 620.3885 483.4476
 [7,] 790.4830 790.4830 790.4830 790.4830 790.4830 790.4830
 [8,] 790.4830 790.4830 790.4830 790.4830 790.4830 790.4830
 [9,] 790.4830 790.4830 790.4830 790.4830 790.4830 790.4830
[10,] 790.4830 790.4830 790.4830 790.4830 790.4830 790.4830
```

I wanted to build a heatmap which was sensitive enough to give each cell its own shade. I tried the following:

```
heatmap(irradiances_shaded_ready_to_use_FINAL[[160]][[1200]], Colv=NA, 
        Rowv=NA, xlab="", ylab="Irradiance", 
        main="Snapshot 1200 day 160", 
        col=colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(64, "Oranges"))(3))
```

...but then the error/warning message is:

```
Warning message:
In brewer.pal(64, "Oranges") :
  n too large, allowed maximum for palette Oranges is 9
Returning the palette you asked for with that many colors
```

Please note: in the above matrix which I pasted above, there are several repeated values, but this is generally not the case. I have like 500,000 such matrices, and I will want to heatmap a small sample of them, but in general I expect that in most cases there will be 64 unique values.

So basically: I need a palette which can illustrate a matrix of 64 unique values. I'm sorry if this is such a simple question.

@jay.sf has suggested that I use "heat.colors (etc etc)," but this doesn't work for me. See the heatmap below: the top four rows are left unshaded, while they should be.

[image]

Comment: What's wrong with `col=heat.colors(64)`?

Comment: A nice idea but unfortunately it fails to colour all of the cells which I want it to. I will post an image as an edit to my original question.

Comment: When you look at your matrix, in the corresponding rows where the heatmap is unshaded, there's no variation at all, i.e. there is no "heat", perhaps that might be your problem. The area even stays white when you do `col="red"`.

Comment: Perhaps I chose the wrong example here, but like I said there's about half a million such matrices and I have this problem even with examples of a matrix where each cell is different. You could say that the color palette isn't sensitive enough.

Comment: Got it! `heatmap` defaults to `scale="row"` where you probably want `"none"`, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend `RColorBrewer` palettes using the base `colorRampPalette` function:

```
library(RColorBrewer)
colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(8, "Oranges"))(64)
```

I also recommend using `pheatmap::pheatmap`. You provide a numeric matrix + a vector of 100 colors and it does the rest for you.

```
library(pheatmap)
data <- matrix(rnorm(100), ncol = 10)
pheatmap(mat = data, color = colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(8, "Oranges"))(100))
```

Comment: I've tried this and I'm afraid it doesn't work.

Comment: What `RColorBrewer` loaded? What happened when you tried?

Comment: See the picture above. It's the same thing. If I use brewer.pal(8, "Oranges)(64), I get the same thing: top four rows are not shaded, and I really kind of want them all to be shaded.

Comment: I remember having trouble with `heatmap` and `col` in the past. I recommend trying `pheatmap::pheatmap` instead, you provide a matrix + a vector of 100 colors and it does the rest for you. See my updated answer

Comment: I appreciate this, but unfortunately it now gives me the following error: Error in as.character(col) %in% "0" : attempt to apply non-function

Comment: See my self-contained example, you should be able to copy it into your console and see what's different

Comment: You're right, that works. Not sure why/how it didn't work when I was just trying to parrot it. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

By default `heatmap` uses `scale="row"`, where also available `"column"` and `"none"`. I think the latter is what you need, because a row with no variation gets scaled to zero and thus would appear unshaded. When you do `col=heat.colors(64)`, the "problematic" rows are in a very light color. The trick is to add a number of surplus colors and subset to 64 colors.

```
heatmap(m, Colv=NA, Rowv=NA,
        xlab="", ylab="Irradiance", 
        main="Snapshot 1200 day 160", 
        col=heat.colors(64+6)[1:64], scale="none")
```

[image]

---

```
m <- structure(c(560.5681, 556.7537, 570.1362, 564.1036, 606.317, 
555.8331, 790.483, 790.483, 790.483, 790.483, 526.3265, 525.3711, 
534.5701, 538.4911, 583.7723, 576.4716, 790.483, 790.483, 790.483, 
790.483, 501.4808, 460.2989, 461.2309, 593.1357, 536.8325, 642.0229, 
790.483, 790.483, 790.483, 790.483, 447.4124, 412.7424, 476.0936, 
573.0606, 614.4326, 617.1337, 790.483, 790.483, 790.483, 790.483, 
475.3496, 478.107, 509.148, 532.7869, 514.1198, 620.3885, 790.483, 
790.483, 790.483, 790.483, 487.1298, 506.8339, 491.3332, 496.5737, 
427.6375, 483.4476, 790.483, 790.483, 790.483, 790.483), .Dim = c(10L, 
6L))
```